# Pandas add single cell vertically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to add a single cell to df but before column names(see image below/Example). Is it possible via pandas? Had two ideas, to merge/concat/append two df vertically, of which one would only be a single cell or to `df.loc` a single cell, but no luck.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Construction Type': [combo2.get()],'Panel Type': [int(upis_tickness)]}, columns['Construction Type', 'Panel Type'])

df_cell = pd.DataFrame([['Panel Schedule - Manufacturing']])

result_df = pd.concat([df, df_cell], axis=1)
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXIC7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, what you need is `MultiIndex`:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Panel Schedule - Manufacturing'], 
                                  ['Construction Type', 'Panel Type']])
df = (pd.DataFrame({'Construction Type': [combo2.get()],
                   'Panel Type': [int(upis_tickness)]})
        .reindex(columns=mux, level=1))
```

**Sample**:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Panel Schedule - Manufacturing'], 
                                  ['Construction Type', 'Panel Type']])
df = (pd.DataFrame({'Construction Type': [1,2],'Panel Type': [5,9]})
        .reindex(columns=mux, level=1))

print (df)

  Panel Schedule - Manufacturing           
               Construction Type Panel Type
0                              1          5
1                              2          9
```

EDIT:

If want write to excel to first row is possible use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Construction Type': [1,2],'Panel Type': [5,9]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow = 1, index=False)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

text = 'Panel Schedule - Manufacturing'
worksheet.write(0, 0, text)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Excellent! I have a new problem now, I must use index. NotImplementedError: Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented. Is there a way around it?

Comment: @MarkoZg - How use index?

Comment: @MarkoZg - Added new simplier solution, added text to first row after `DataFrame` is written, answer was edited.